# Initial structures in the category of algebraic systems of the same type

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

From [Handbook of Analysis and Its Foundations by Eric Schechter](http://books.google.com/books?id=eqUv3Bcd56EC&lpg=PA220&dq=%22Basic%20properties%20of%20subalgebras%22&pg=PA220#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> 9.21. Basic properties of subalgebras. We consider the category consisting of the algebraic systems of some type $(τ, \mathcal{J})$, with
>   homomorphisms of type $τ$. (For examples, think of the category of
>   lattices, the category of rings, or the category of lattice groups.)
>   In this category, a subobject is called a subalgebra. Let $X$ be an
>   object.
>
> $Y$ is a subalgebra of $X$ if and only if $Y$ is a subset of $X$ that
>   is closed under the fundamental operations of $X$. It then follows
>   that $Y$ itself is also an algebraic system of type $(τ, \mathcal{J})$, whose
>   fundamental operations are the restrictions to $Y$ of the fundamental
>   operations of $X$.
>
> Except in degenerate cases, **not every subset of $X$ is closed under
>   the fundamental operations. Thus, in an algebraic category, initial
>   structures do not always exist.**

I was wondering how to understand why "in an algebraic category, initial
 structures do not always exist" is because "not every subset of $X$ is closed under the fundamental operations".

Is "initial structures" same as the concept of initial object in the category? Isn't the initial object the empty set?
[image]
What does $\mathcal{J}$ mean? I know $\tau$ is the arity function and it itself can be called the type.

Thanks!

Comment: No, initial structure is not the same as initial object. As best as I can tell it corresponds to the notion of the [initial lift](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+lift) of a source. (Also, the empty set is not always an initial object,  for the simple reason that the empty set is not always an algebra of the right type!)

Comment: @ZhenLin: I have updated with the definition of initial structure.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the notation has been explained elsewhere in the book. My wild guess is that in $(\tau, \mathcal{J})$ the first symbol $\tau$ describes an algebraic signature, and the second symbol $\mathcal{J}$ denotes a class of logical sentences that have to be satisfied by algebras. For example, you may describe monoids as algebras over signature $\langle \circ/2, \epsilon/0\rangle$ satisfying sentences:
$$\{x \circ (y \circ z) = (x \circ y) \circ z, \epsilon \circ x = x, x \circ \epsilon = x\}$$
An initial structure in (the category of) algebras of type $\tau$ satisfying $\mathcal{J}$ is by definition an initial object in this category.

An initial structure cannot be "the empty set", because the empty set is a set, and an initial structure has to be an algebra. However, in "most cases" the *carrier* of an initial structure is not the empty set either. For example in the category of monoids, the initial structure is the trivial monoid $\langle \{\epsilon\}, \circ, \epsilon \rangle$ (yes, it is also the terminal structure). Initial structures may not exist. For example, if we added an additional sentence:
$$\exists_{x,y} \;x \not= y$$
to the above set of sentences characterizing monoids, then initial structures would not exist.

---

Zhen is right, the definition refers to the concept of "lifting" defined [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+lift). The puzzling thing is that both your book and the referred page interchange the terminology --- what they call an initial lifting is really a terminal lifting, or *cartesian* lifting. And, yes, terminal liftings are terminal objects in appropriate categories.

The “right” terminology comes from fibrations --- if you pick $\Lambda = \{\bullet\}$, then your "initial" structures correspond to the terminal liftings in the underlying functor $U((X, \mathcal{T}) = X$ --- which is a fibration precisely when all $\{\bullet\}$-indexed "initial" structures exist.

Comment: I don't think that's quite what is meant in the book cited. The "initial structure" being discussed is much closer to the notion of initial lifts in e.g. a [topological concrete category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category).

Comment: Mockup, thanks! THe definition is here  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fV3Ea.png